# Running both Xcode 4.6 and Xcode 5 (DP5) - Homebrew showing an error

Tags: ruby, xcode, terminal, homebrew, xcode5

**Context:**

- I have both Xcode 4.6.3 and Xcode 5 (DP5) installed. I've also
  installed command line tools on both (via the preference settings).
- I just installed `Homebrew` and ran `brew doctor` in the terminal and I get the following error:

[image]

**Question**

- Is this likely because I have two versions of Xcode installed?
- Is there a way to fix this?
- Do I need to fix this?

Comment: Do you have a `/Developer` directory?

Comment: Yes I have a `/Developer` folder, I assume I have to uninstall command line tools from one of my Xcode builds?

Comment: It sounds like you might also have an old install of Xcode, or at least bits of one floating around. Homebrew's directions for getting rid of that should work.

Comment: So you don't think its having the Xcode 5 (beta) developer preview installed, along with Xcode 4.6?

Comment: I'd rather not delete Xcode 4.6 as it's the latest stable release, but I also want to build for iOS 7.

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem—I have the latest Xcode 4 and 5, too. Xcode hasn't been installed in `/Developer` for a while, so if you still have that directory it's from a really old install.

Comment: @mipadi maybe set your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to reinstall Xcode. Go to Xcode preferences menu and click on downloads. You will see option to install "Command Line Tools" under Components. After that's installed homebrew stops complaining.